# newman CLI '--export-collection' not outputting updated collection variables

Tags: variables, postman, newman

When using the `newman` CLI (version 5.2.2), there is a requirement to save updated **collection variables** after a run. To achieve this, `-export-collection <path>` is being used but variables in the collection at `<path>` do not contain updated values after a run.

To set a variable value, `pm.collectionVariables.set()` is being used.

```
let jsonResponse = pm.response.json();
pm.collectionVariables.set("myVariable", jsonResponse.value);
```

When testing the request in Postman, the updated variable value persists in the collection. The same is true if the runner is used with **Keep variable values** checked.

However, when using the `newman` CLI the collection variables are not updated after the run.

```
newman run collection.json --environment environment.json --export-collection collection.json
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options), `--export-collection|globals|environment <path>` is -

> The path to the file where Newman will output the final collection / global variables / environment variables file before completing a run.

Testing shows that setting a global/environment variable in the request and using `--export-globals|environment <path>` works, with the output file containing the updated variable value.

Is this a bug with the `newman` CLI, or is there something that can be done to fix this behaviour?

Comment: its better to ask this in postman community forum or github ,

Comment: --export-collection <path>
The path to the file where Newman will output the final collection file before completing a run.

Comment: it says final collection file , as its "final" collection file i think it should have the updated variable also .

Comment: But it doesn't says anything specific about variables so not sure if that is the expectation of that flag